# Ember js: How to retrieve the underlying model from a controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to retrieve the underlying model object from a controller so that it can be persisted (I am not using ember-data). The obvious way would simply be:

```
controller.get('content');
```

But this doesn't work. The problem can be summed up as follows:

```
controller.set("content", model);
```

sets the content as expected and at this point

```
controller.get('content');
```

works as expected. But if I then decorate the controller with other properties eg.

```
controller.set('IamNotPartOfTheModel', false);
```

then suddenly the 'content' includes this new property. I would've expected the content to remain unchanged and the new property to only be applied to the controller itself. I understand the controller is a proxy for the model so for the most part they are treated as one and the same but surely they should still be separable when needed? The whole point of this pattern is to separate data that should be stored from data that is just temporary. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your display specific properties out of the model, just specify them explicitly in the controller... Otherwise the controller acts as a proxy for its model... just have the property "iamNotPartOfTheModel" in your controller

```
   App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     iamNotPartOfTheModel: null
   })
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/ikijoq/5/edit)

Comment: This will work for my purposes, thanks! Although I still don't particularly like it - I don't think all the non-model properties should have to be explicitly declared in the controller when some of them are being set up in the route handler, but oh well.

Comment: I found that the behaviour I am looking for is the default behaviour of the base controller. So declaring the controller using `Ember.Controller.extend` is another option. But then of course you lose the functionality of the ObjectController, but in my case that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to interface to some kind of model. You can't separate the persisted model from the controller except by some kind of object reference. Even if you don't use ember-data, you'll still need to create objects which then plug into the content of the controller. Have a look at [Evil Trout's blog](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) for an implementation of ember without ember-data. Its a great starting point.